# mongo replicaset right connection

Tags: mongodb

I have a problem.Server manager told us to use cluster for mongo settings.He gave to me 3 ip numbers and a replicaset name.

I wrote a setting like this;

```
new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://root:password@ip1:27017,ip2:27017,ip3:27017/databaseName?replicaSet=company_mongo);
```

---

I have a code like

```
<?php


$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite();

$bulk->insert(['_id' => 3333333]);

$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://root:pass@ip1:27017,ip2:27017,ip3:27017/databaseName?replicaSet=company_mongo);

$writeConcern = new MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern(MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern::MAJORITY, 100);

try {
  $result = $manager->executeBulkWrite('test.foo', $bulk, $writeConcern);
}
catch(\Exception $e){
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($e);
  echo '</pre>';
}

?>
```

**I had run this code before, it worked correctly.

But today we are getting the following error.**

```
MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException Object
(
    [message:protected] => 
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 13053
    [file:protected] => /../mongotest.php
    [line:protected] => 22
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /../mongotest.php
                    [line] => 22
                    [function] => executeBulkWrite
                    [class] => MongoDB\Driver\Manager
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => test.foo
                            [1] => MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite Object
                                (
                                    [database] => 
                                    [collection] => 
                                    [ordered] => 1
                                    [bypassDocumentValidation] => 
                                    [executed] => 
                                    [server_id] => 0
                                    [write_concern] => 
                                )

                            [2] => MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern Object
                                (
                                    [w] => majority
                                    [wtimeout] => 100
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [previous:Exception:private] => 
)
```

Could you help me with the cause of this problem?

Comment: Why not to ask the *server manager* ? The db is not accessible anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It's a ConnectionTimeoutException, there are two things that can go wrong because of which you are seeing the exception:

- Confirm that all three mongo servers are up and running. If only 1 server is running, `w = majority` will never succeed
- Confirm with your server manager, if there is latency between the 3 mongo servers. `wtimeout = 100` means 2 out of 3 (one primary and one secondary) servers must apply the writes within 100 ms.

It is very much possible that writes are already happening on the Primary Mongo Server. So, if it's possible, connect to it directly to confirm the same.